# generated paths are wrong formatted with html-webpack-plugin

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I'm building `vue.js` application with webpack2 on Windows 10, the issue is with the generated path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="\js\main.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

---

`html-webpack-plugin` configuration:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "src/html/index.html",
      inject: true,
      chunksSortMode: "dependency"
    })
```

Thanx in advance for any help,

Comment: Your last code block doesn't show the place where the path is set. Have you made the setup yourself or are you using a cli template for example?

Comment: I'm using laravel-mix to configure webpack, but the issue is not with the configuration it's with the plugin, as it generates the bundle file correctly without the plugin but when I use the plugin the path change